# Entity Framework Include and Select are gettind some other entities

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework 6 latest stable version with Northwind database. And I wrote a query like below. Even I didn't include customer to order. And also included entity OrderDetails has Order (this is like recursion). And the final included entity Product of OrderDetails has Category even I didn't include. The weird thing is Supplier is a navigation property but it is null for product.

Plus : LazyLoading and ProxyCreationEnabled is false

```
var orders = Context.Orders
            .Include(i => i.Order_Details)
            .Include(i => i.Order_Details.Select(a => a.Product))
            .Where(i => i.EmployeeID == employeeId && i.CustomerID == customerId)
            .ToList();
```

[image: Product property on Order]

And OrderDetail's issue

[image: Category and Supplier is so weird]

What I can't catch on this?

Comment: if supplier is null means data will not be there in your repository

Comment: Because I don't want Supplier, well I don't want Category too. There is no Include on query as you see

Comment: Well, you didn't `Include` Supplier, and we don't know if everything is setup properly to support lazy loading of Supplier. Probably not. You have to show your mapping for us to be able to say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a select if you dont want unwanted data from table.you can do by anonymous select or using view-model Class

```
 var orders = Context.Orders
            .Include(i => i.Order_Details)
            .Include(i => i.Order_Details.Select(a => a.Product))
            .Where(i => i.EmployeeID == employeeId && i.CustomerID == customerId)
            .Select new
             {
                //here you can select the fields which all are you required
             }
```

or

```
            .Select new requireddatavm
             {
                //here you can select the fields which all are you required
             }
```

In method syntax, with other operators:

```
.Where(i => i.EmployeeID == employeeId && i.CustomerID == customerId)
```

, returns the whole row including included fields